# How to measure a distance with a ultrasonic sensor in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to measure a distance with ultrasonic sensor and everything looks well but when I leave the program for a some minutes (3-4 minutes) working, the program stops the measure of distance.

I need that the program dont stops because I need it to a security alarm. The program collects every one second a distance and show it in scree. But if distance is more than 10, the program shows a alert message and dont show the distance until it is less of 10. Following you can see the code:

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


# Usamos la referencia BOARD para los pines GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Definimos los pines que vamos a usar
GPIO_TRIGGER = 11
GPIO_ECHO = 13
GPIO_LED = 15

# Configuramos los pines como entradas y salidas
GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER,GPIO.OUT)  # Trigger
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO,GPIO.IN)      # Echo
GPIO.setup(GPIO_LED ,GPIO.OUT) #Led


# -----------------------
# Definimos algunas funciones
# -----------------------

def medida():
  # Esta funcion mide una distancia
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
  time.sleep(0.00001)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
  start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==0:
    start = time.time()

  while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO)==1:
    stop = time.time()

  elapsed = stop-start
  distancia = (elapsed * 34300)/2

  return distancia

def media_distancia():
  # Esta funcion recoge 3 medidas
  # y devuelve la media de las 3.
  distancia1=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia2=medida()
  time.sleep(0.1)
  distancia3=medida()
  distancia = distancia1 + distancia2 + distancia3
  distancia = distancia / 3
  return distancia


# -----------------------
# Programa principal
# -----------------------


print ("Medida con sensor de ultrasonidos")

# Ponemos el Trigger en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
# Ponemos el Led en falso (low)
GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)

# Metemos el bloque principal en un Try para asi poder
# comprobar si el usuario presiona Ctrl + C
# y poder ejecutar una limpieza del GPIO, esto tambien
# evita el usuario tener que ver muchos mensajes de error
try:
  while True: # Este bucle se repite siempre

# Lo primero que hago es medir la distancia
      distancia = media_distancia()
# Compruebo si la distancia es menor que 10
# Si es menor que 10 muestro la distancia por pantalla

      if distancia < 10:
        distancia = media_distancia() # Medidos la distancia 
        print ("Distancia: %.1f" % distancia, " - " , "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Mostramos la distancia por pantalla
        GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
        time.sleep(1) # Esperamos 1 segundo
        distancia = media_distancia()
        a = 0 # Utilizo la variable a para poder para el proceso mas adelante

# Pregunto si la variable a es igual a 1
# Si lo es no hago nada y repito el if anterior
      if a == 1:
        pass
# Pero si no es 1 le asigno el valor 0
# Para poder seguir con el IF siguiente
      else: 
        a = 0
      if distancia > 10 and a == 0: # Si la distancia es mayor que 10cms
           print ("La distancia es mayor de 10 cms. Alarma activada!!", " - ", "Fecha:", time.strftime("%c")) # Se interrumpe el bucle y se muestra un aviso
           GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, True)  
           a = 1 # Pongo la variable en 1 para parar el proceso y que no se repita 
           distancia = media_distancia() # Seguimos midiento la distancia
           while distancia < 10: # Pero si la distancia vuelve a ser menor de 10
             break # Se termina este bucle y volvemos al principio nuevamente

except KeyboardInterrupt: # Si el usuario presiona crtl + C

  # Limpiamos los pines GPIO y salimos del programa

  print ("Apagando LED")
  time.sleep(1)
  GPIO.output(GPIO_LED, False)
  print ("Limpiando GPIO")
  GPIO.cleanup()
  print ("GPIO limpio")
  print ("Saliendo...")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Why the program stops after some minutes? The program ins running but it does not collects more distances.

[image: does not collects more distances]